# ECLiPSe CLP puzzle: perfect rectangle fitting

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, eclipse-clp

I'm working on a puzzle known as 'divide-by-box'. In essence, it's a form of perfect rectangle fitting, based on given clues. The rules are:

- Some grid cells contain numbers (this is known input data)
- The task is to partition the grid area into rectangular rooms satisfying following constraints: each room contains exactly one number and the total area of the room is equal to the number in it

## E.g.:

```
4 _ 2
_ _ _
_ 3 _
```

has solution:

```
+-----------+
| 4  . | 2  |
| .  . | .  |
|------+----+
| .   3  .  |
+-----------+
```

I have written constraints and a small finite domain solver which efficiently gives me all possible rectangle placements per hint, like so (coordinates start at (1,1) and move from top-left to bottom-right) :

```
% Syntax: rectangle(X,Y,Width,Height,HintValue)
[
  [rectangle(1, 1, 2, 2, 4)],
  [rectangle(2, 1, 2, 1, 2), rectangle(3, 1, 1, 2, 2)],
  [rectangle(1, 3, 3, 1, 3), rectangle(2, 1, 1, 3, 3)]
]
```

I subsequently tried to write my own solver which is based upon checking for overlapping constraints (i.e. if two rectangles overlap horizontally, they should not overlap vertically and vice versa). It works okay for small puzzles, however, neither of my attempts successfully scaled up to puzzles greater than ~ 15x15 because of the extensive constraint checking.

So the goal is to find a model that will scale up to larger puzzles and if possible, in such a way that it is possible to use ECLiPSe's built-in search/6 and be able to easily experiment with different search heuristics.

Any thoughts/ideas? Thanks in advance!

NOTE :  I'm working with the integer IC domain library (= lib(ic))

(**edit** they now all solve in less than half a second in case someone is interested in the running time results)

Problem input data:

> Syntax: problem(ID,Width,Height,Hints)  (Hints are triplet-tuples: (I,J,Value))
>
> problem(p(15,1),15,15,[(9,1,4),(11,1,2),(12,1,3),(14,1,3),(2,2,4),(3,2,2),(4,2,2),(8,2,12),(2,3,3),(10,3,3),(1,4,2),(10,4,11),(15,5,7),(8,7,36),(12,8,24),(3,9,27),(13,9,24),(15,9,7),(4,11,3),(8,11,2),(7,12,6),(8,12,2),(7,13,3),(8,13,2),(10,13,3),(4,14,7),(9,14,3),(10,14,2),(11,14,2),(12,14,6),(6,15,8)]).
>
> problem(p(15,2),15,15,[(1,1,9),(11,1,2),(13,1,2),(7,3,36),(13,4,3),(14,4,16),(1,6,2),(7,6,24),(4,7,3),(6,7,8),(2,8,6),(3,8,3),(9,8,7),(7,9,9),(15,9,5),(1,10,5),(3,10,2),(11,10,16),(14,10,5),(1,12,2),(4,12,2),(6,12,3),(10,12,6),(11,12,2),(3,13,3),(7,13,2),(12,13,5),(13,13,7),(1,14,2),(14,14,26),(15,14,2)]).
>
> problem(p(20,1),20,20,[(2,1,2),(4,1,2),(11,1,4),(13,1,2),(1,2,2),(5,2,12),(9,2,35),(16,3,15),(19,3,20),(1,4,2),(1,5,2),(4,6,8),(20,6,5),(14,7,2),(3,8,10),(10,8,5),(1,10,4),(5,11,30),(15,13,60),(7,14,24),(12,14,54),(14,14,13),(9,15,54),(1,16,8),(16,18,6),(17,18,3),(19,18,2),(20,18,8),(20,19,3),(18,20,3)]).
>
> problem(p(20,2),20,20,[(3,1,3),(6,1,2),(8,1,4),(2,2,2),(4,2,4),(9,2,3),(16,2,15),(17,2,3),(18,2,6),(11,3,2),(19,3,2),(20,3,3),(1,4,4),(5,4,7),(9,4,2),(17,4,7),(19,4,2),(4,5,5),(9,5,2),(10,5,3),(12,5,9),(1,6,2),(2,6,2),(7,6,18),(2,7,2),(10,7,2),(13,7,20),(1,9,20),(20,9,3),(4,10,3),(11,10,45),(15,12,28),(19,12,2),(20,12,2),(5,13,2),(8,13,3),(15,13,40),(6,14,2),(9,14,12),(3,15,14),(5,15,4),(6,15,6),(18,15,18),(3,16,2),(4,16,6),(5,18,3),(14,18,15),(17,18,2),(3,19,2),(5,19,4),(10,19,2),(2,20,6),(5,20,3),(6,20,2),(8,20,3),(16,20,2),(17,20,2),(20,20,6)]).
>
> problem(p(25,1),25,25,[(2,1,2),(11,1,10),(15,1,8),(17,1,8),(24,1,2),(13,2,2),(14,2,2),(3,3,6),(12,3,32),(25,3,2),(2,4,2),(4,4,2),(14,4,2),(24,4,8),(25,4,2),(4,5,3),(14,5,4),(13,7,2),(1,8,18),(18,8,56),(21,9,6),(22,9,3),(25,9,4),(2,10,6),(19,10,18),(24,10,4),(10,11,60),(14,11,10),(15,11,4),(23,11,3),(2,12,2),(4,12,5),(10,12,4),(22,12,2),(23,12,3),(24,12,6),(6,13,15),(19,13,2),(21,13,2),(2,14,2),(5,14,28),(17,14,3),(20,14,3),(22,14,2),(18,15,3),(21,15,5),(7,16,7),(12,16,3),(15,16,3),(16,16,2),(9,17,2),(11,17,2),(17,17,3),(20,17,16),(7,18,12),(8,18,2),(9,18,3),(12,18,4),(13,18,9),(19,18,12),(24,18,2),(25,18,3),(1,19,2),(5,19,9),(11,19,2),(3,20,2),(5,20,5),(9,20,2),(20,20,7),(7,21,24),(18,22,6),(20,22,3),(21,22,10),(4,23,6),(5,23,3),(7,23,9),(10,23,12),(16,23,24),(17,23,4),(24,23,5),(1,24,2),(18,24,8),(25,24,2),(2,25,4),(17,25,11)]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can formulate the whole problem in terms of finite-domain constraints and then solve it with a standard search routine. There is no need to pre-compute lists of individual rectangle placements.

In case this is homework, let me just give some recommendations.  I would start by defining a number of auxiliary predicates like

```
rect_contains_point(rect(I,J,K,L), point(PI,PJ)) :-
    I #=< PI, PI #=< K,
    J #=< PJ, PJ #=< L.
```

which come in handy in formulating the overall model. Here I've used `rect(I,J,K,L)` to represent a rectangle with corners `(I,J)` and `(K,L)`, as this turns out to be more convenient for formulating the necessary constraints.

You can then write the non-overlap condition as

```
no_overlap(rect(I1,J1,K1,L1), rect(I2,J2,K2,L2)) :-
    K1#<I2 or K2#<I1 or L1#<J2 or L2#<J1.
```

which is the same method that you find in the [tiling example](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/square_tiling.pl.txt) on the [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) web site.

## EDIT

Thanks for providing the problem instances. I get solutions for all of them, and also for today's 30x40 puzzle, in less than 1.5 seconds.

Interestingly, you get the best performance with the most naive labeling strategy `input_order`.  For such problems with simple geometric structure it is often best to label variables based on their "adjacency" in the geometry, and simply using the row-wise order works fine here.

Still, especially for problems with additional constraints that perturb the simple structure, this approach may not scale up sufficiently.  For this reason, people have developed specialised placement/packing constraints, see e.g. [`disjoint2` in SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Placement-Constraints.html) or [`nooverlap` in Gecode](http://www.gecode.org/doc/4.3.3/reference/group__TaskModelIntGeoPacking.html). The latter is also available in ECLiPSe via [`disjoint2/1` in `library(gfd)`](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/gfd/disjoint2-1.html).

## PS

As reported by @SeekAndDestroy, the labeling strategy `smallest` (selecting the variable with the currently smallest value in its domain) gives even better results.  Also, using `library(gfd)` instead of `library(ic)` gives further speedup.  I have added [my solution](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/shikaku.ecl.txt) to the examples at the ECLiPSe web site.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's actually quite an honour to receive an answer from you, since I've read and got inspired by several of your works. Eclipse clp is truly an amazing system!

On-topic: I've just implemented the model approach you suggested in which I don't pre-compute possible rectangles and work with corner coordinates and it is a really succesfull improvement given the much simpler overlapping constraints. This implementation can efficiently handle most 15x15 puzzles and even various 20x20 puzzles, however it's still not scalable enough. I will edit my post with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, and the puzzle instances. I have amended my answer.

Comment: It appears -for my code- if I change the selection method from input_order to smallest, all puzzles are solved within less than half a second using the new model. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, I could swear I tried that and it was slower... But you are right, and it makes sense. Anyway, I added a link to my final code, which includes this improvement.